# Table View moves around after reorientation

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, landscape-portrait, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using autolayout and i've set the options leading space to superview (constant 0), trailing space to superview (constant 0) and center horizontally to supeview in a table view.

Even though, when coming back from landscape mode, the table view becomes movable you can drag it around i doesn't seem to be attached to the edges of the superview, and it seems that happens because the table view was wider in landscape mode and when it goes back to portrait mode there's some blank room left to the right of the table view to fill the space is not longer ocuppying.

I call this code in every re orientation:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [General addLeftRightConstraintsToView:_detail1TableView inRelationToSuperview:self.navigationController.view];
}
```

That's a class method i'm using to update layout constraints:

```
+ (void)addLeftRightConstraintsToView:(UIView *)view inRelationToSuperview:(UIView *)superview
{

    // Left Space to Superview
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftSpaceConstraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:superview
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0.0];

    // Right Space to Superview
    NSLayoutConstraint *rightSpaceConstraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:superview
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0.0];

    [superview addConstraint:leftSpaceConstraint];
    [superview addConstraint:rightSpaceConstraint];

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [_details2TableView reloadData];
}
```